# Storing into a Java Array through OnClickListener

Tags: java, arrays

I'm sorry if this comes through as a "noob" question, but I'm really stuck and I couldn't find any help, no matter where I looked.

The problem I'm having is this:

The user fills out a textbox saying how many numbers (doubles) he is going to input next (say n)

I store that number inside the OnClickListener method (that works ok)

```
public double n;
//CODE

n = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
```

I then need to store the n numbers that the user will input

He will fill out the textbox, press enter and the number should be stored in an array

Something like:

```
int i = n;
double x[] = new double[n];

button1.onClick(View view){
   x[i] = Double.parseDouble(input.getText().toString());
   i--;
}
```

No matter how I declare the x[i] I get an error message. I've done some debugging and the error pops up whenever storring in the array occurs. I know I'm missed out something basic about this and I feel pretty dumb for getting stuck with this, but I'd really appreciate any help or suggestion you guys might have.

Thanks a lot, Eugene

P.S. I have to declare the array AFTER "n" has been inputted, however when I try to use it in the next OnClickListener, it can't access it unless it's declared final, or as a class variable (public/private etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double x[] = new double[n];
```

should be `double[] x = new double[n];`

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 10;
        double[] x = new double[n];
        x[5] = 7;
        x[1] = 31;
        for(double i: x) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

Edit:
You need to call `i--;` before `x[i] = Double.parseDouble(input.getText().toString());` if you call `new double[10]` then only `x[0]` through `x[9]` are valid pointers.

Comment: Thank you, but that is not my problem. I know how to handle such operations easily. My problem is that when I am trying to store INSIDE the onClickListener method, the app always force closes.

Comment: You're probably getting an array out of bounds error.  See edit above

Comment: No...it's not that. Sorry for wasting your time and thanks for all your answers. Thing is, whenever I try something like x[0] = input or x[1] or whatever, it crashes...